# Change video tone into sepia

Tags: python, opencv

I used Python to change the tone of the video into sepia. Here's what I used using OpenCV:

```
def sepia(rgb):
    b,g,r = cv2.split(rgb)
    red = r * 0.393 + g* 0.769 + b* 0.189
    green = r * 0.349 +g * 0.686 + b* 0.168
    blue = r* 0.272 + g* 0.534 + b * 0.131
    return cv2.merge((blue,green,red))
```

My output is:

[image: Screenshot!]

**Update**

It seems that, when I used

```
pt.imshow(gray, cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray'))
```

it shows a perfect grayscale, while this:

```
cv2.imshow('GrayscaleThis',gray)
```

shows a black and white image.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, since you didn't post the code.  Note that imshow has its way of interpreting the type of the input array, see [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#imshow):

> - If the image is 8-bit unsigned, it is displayed as is.
> - If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256. That is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to
>     [0,255].
> - If the image is 32-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied by 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to
>     [0,255].